# laravel model working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Booking extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'bookings';
    protected $guarded = [];

    const CREATED_AT = 'created';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'modified';

    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BookingDetail::class);
    }

    public function billing_information()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(BillingInfo::class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$data = [
    // ...
];

// Saving Booking Information
$booking = new Booking();
$booking->fill($data); //if var_dump here data found
$booking->save(); // if var_dump here no response
```

But data does not insert into desired table on server.
But it works perfectly on local.
Checked log file both storage and server. No error found.
Used `try` and `catch` but nothing happened.
Already tried `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear`

Any idea why its not working on server ?

Comment: What are the server and local os?

Comment: server ubuntu and local windows

Comment: And PHP versions? I see `protected $guarded = [];` - php7 syntax. Maybe You've got older version on server?

Comment: nope ... PHP 7.2.4

Comment: Based on os, double check the letters (A vs a) every where.

Comment: why $data array is empty

Comment: it contains data .. just did not paste here

Comment: What database on production? Check `autocommit` option.

Comment: mysql and enabled

Comment: server settings in my opinion

Comment: did you check $booking = Booking::create($data);

Comment: What do you mean by "no response"? What's the result of `var_dump($booking->save());`?